# updating from bootstrap 3.2.0 to 3.3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, upgrade, updates

i made a website styled by twitter bootstrap v3.2.0 Arabic version(Right to Left ) using 
bootstrap-3.2.0-dist , Now i want to upgrade it with the latest version 3.3.4 
How could i do this successfully ?

Comment: Should be as simple as using the news CSS and JS files.

Comment: Yes i think that but actually how to do that without any conflict ?
i searched in stackoverflow and other sites and i found many solutions but to upgrade from v2 to v3

Comment: There is no conflict. Remove the old files, add the new ones.